# DynamoDB AWS best way to retrieve data in a recurring way

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So as the question states, I have a dynamoDB setup from which I am fetching data. My User end is configured in iOS, hence I am using the AWS iOS SDK. Although the documentation is alright, but its outdated a lot, and going through the documentations, many classes are deprecated.

I have 2 questions -

1. I have to fetch the latest entry from the DB always, so I am doing this by setting the `scanforward = false and limit = 1` . Now I am calling `query` method from the `dynamoDBObjectMapper`, but there is also load method which also can be configured to do the same. My first question is that what is the difference between `query` and `load` if I have to fetch only the latest entry in the DB. Also what is the correct way to retrieve it?
2. I have to fetch this data in the most instantaneous way possible. I know about `DynamoDBStream`, but that is NOT an option. Basically I have to implement a long polling kind of feature, where I will get a call? whenever any data is changed OR continuously fetch data from the dynamoDB at a particular interval. Shall i use NSTimer and the same method call (`load vs query`) to fetch the latest entry in the DB?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also if any developer working in Amazon can see this question, please remove the old documentation from AWS console and keep the latest ones. There are 5 documentation on the same thing, and all of them are outdated and deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing that out. Can you give the links of the documentation that has deprecated classes? We will try to keep the latest ones and remove if there are any redundant deprecated references.

1. load() API is used to retrieve an item: Using an object's primary key load the corresponding item from the database. Look for an example here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb-object-mapper.html under "Retrieve an item" section.
   query() API can be used to return any number of records that match the query. The query API enables you to query a table or a secondary index.
   To answer your question, if you know the primary key of the record that you are trying to retrieve, you can use load() API, otherwise use query() API.
2. DynamoDBStreams work well for your use case. Otherwise you can intgerate AWS Lambda with DynamoDB table to do polling which will be cleaner than a timer based approach. This question is partially answered here: [Hooks for AWS DynamoDB streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636166/hooks-for-aws-dynamodb-streams)

Comment: Hi, I am going through another problem with AWS now, I have followed the AWS cognito documentation, but now I want to incorporate User Pools. 
Please tell me first of all : Which framework do i use? I use cocoapods but using that, I am unable to login in my console created user from the application. 
Also the framework from cocoapods, the TokenID is not persistant. Delegate for logging in is always called, even after i have already logged in.
I am geting to know there are static libraries avaliable with mobile HUB, but they follow a different set of class. Which one should i go first?